# Time function in python

Tags: python, performance, time, python-3.x

I'm a new python programmer, got a simple question, I'm sure it had been answered before but couldn't find an answer.

Anyways, when I used the time function in python i had received: 8.731943940129682e-05  sec.
what does the e-05 mean? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's scientific notation applied to computing. `E-05` means 10 to the power of -5:

```
8.73194...E-05 = 8.73194 * 10^(-5) = 0.000 087 319 4...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it:

```
>>> '{:.9f} sec'.format(8.731943940129682e-05)
'0.000087319 sec'
>>> '{:.15f} sec'.format(8.731943940129682e-05)
'0.000087319439401 sec'
```